# Heroku “failed to compile Multipack app”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gruntjs

I'm trying to deploy Rails + Grunt + Heroku, like this(http://www.angularonrails.com/deploy-angular-rails-single-page-application-heroku/)

But I got this message

```
 $ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 24, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (24/24), 3.24 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 24 (delta 14), reused 17 (delta 8)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/getgamba/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt-compass.git

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app
```

How should I solve this problem?

Could you help me?

/root/.buildpacks

```
https://github.com/getgamba/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt-compass.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

/root/front/package.json

```
    {
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.7.3",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-connect-proxy": "^0.1.11",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^0.2.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.10.1",
    "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-ngmin": "^0.0.3",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-rails-server": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt-shell-spawn": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^2.1.1",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^1.7.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.1.3",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.2.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^0.4.0",
    "source-map": "^0.1.37",
    "time-grunt": "^0.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try configuring Heroku to expect multiple buildpacks.  I had a similar problem and solved it with:

`heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your child buildpacks don't fails their project checks.

For example Ruby buildpack requires `Gemfile` to be present in the project root - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby#ruby

Node.js is likely to look for you `packages.json` or whatever.